# Резкий скачок влияния

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, профиль-участника

Заметил [у себя в профиле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186083/visman?tab=profile) скачок цифры во влиянии.

Вчера эта цифра была то ли 83, то ли 93 тысячи, а сегодня с утра 137 тыс.

Откуда это?

Comment: Кто-то скинул ссылку на страницу с вашим сообщением в китайском или индийском форуме и понеслось...

Comment: @alexolut, они там на русском что ли шпарят :)

Comment: язык кода интернационален! :)